# jquery Tablesorter pager not disabling the buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, tablesorter

I am newly using jquery tablesorter with pager add on. It works fine with sorting. When i go for pagination, it's not adding disabled class to the buttons when it reaches the extreme pages. FYI, my pagerOption is

```
     {
            container: $('#pager'),
            size: 2,
            positionFixed: false,
            updateArrows: true,
            cssNext: '.next',
            cssPrev: '.prev',
            cssFirst: '.first',
            cssLast: '.last',
            cssPageDisplay: '.pagedisplay',
            cssPageSize: '.pagesize',
            cssDisabled: 'disabled',             
            cssErrorRow: 'tablesorter-errorRow',
      }
```

And one more thing, i'm using div and form elements. I think it is not the cause, other pager functions works fine except this. Kindly help.

Comment: provide us the html part, and why don't you create a jsfiddle sample.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/5FeFK/ but its just the table part and js part, it is not working in jsfiddle

Comment: Do you get any errors on the chrome console?

Comment: It works in [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/4mVfu/1/), are you including the pager css?